# Match items from 2 different counters

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, match, counter

I have the outputs from 2 counters:

```
counter1: (a:1, e:4, x:2)
counter2: (x:5, a:8, e:4)
```

I want this output:

```
a: 1/8, e: 4/4, x: 2/5
```

Any suggestions on how to match the i with their respective counts in both counters and divide?

This is just a sample, my actual data is 10000s of variables long.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through counters:

```
from collections import Counter
counter1 = Counter(['a'] + ['e'] * 4 + ['x'] * 2)
counter2 = Counter(['x'] * 5 + ['a'] * 8 + ['e'] * 4)
for k in counter1 : 
    counter1[k] = counter1[k]/counter2[k]
```

This assumes that every key ('k') in counter1 appears in counter2, otherwise you'll encounter a division by zero error. Counters are similar to dicts in that you can iterate through keys and values using counter1.items(). Note if you don't want to update counter1 you can initialise a new counter and update its values.